# Save time left on setInterval() after reloading page?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, cookies

I am making a webpage that is supposed to serve as a place to take a break, and all html elements will hide after 5 minutes and show again after 30, but currently this cooldown can be bypassed by simply reloading the page. I was going to try using localStorage.setItem(), but I'm not sure how I would get the time left on the interval to save or update it. my code is here.

```html
<script>

var body = document.querySelector('body')
    
    setInterval(()=>{
        body.style.display = 'initial' ;
        setTimeout(()=>{
              body.style.display = 'none'
        }, 300000)
     }, 180000)


</script> 
<body>
<h1>example html</h1>

</body
```

Comment: So you got to use localstorage. Store the end time in localstorage. If they leave and come back you read localstorage and set a value

Comment: use javascript cookies, that mean if users refresh the page they will got the the same time's value. The missing line is : document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";

Comment: Someone could just delete the localstorage though

Comment: The cookies can cleaned by the users and the session can closed  by close the browser by users too. If using the database you can storage use adress, him initial time (the time when he entre your page), after that can use him initial time to check if him time is done or not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const aMinute = 60000;
let d = localStorage.getItem("d"); 
let now = new Date().getTime;
let end = d ? new Date(d) : new Date().getTime();
let tId = setInterval(()=>{
  now = new Date().getTime;
  body.classList.toggle("initial",now-end > 0);
}, 180000)
// some event to set
localStorage.setItem("d",(new Date().getTime()+5*aMinute));
```

```html
<h1>example html</h1>
```

Comment: So is this in the place of my previous code, before, or after it?

Comment: It’s just an idea - you can use bits and pieces

Comment: Okay. I'm fairly new to javascript though, so that was the only reason i was asking. Thanks!